# trigger functions with radio buttons React/TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have radio buttons that look like this:

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-4">
        <label className="radio">
            <input onChange={() => {serviceCalc()}} type="radio" name="radio-btn-product" value="standard" id="standard" checked />
            <i></i>Standard
        </label>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-4">
        <label className="radio">
            <input onChange={() => {serviceCalc()}} type="radio" name="radio-btn-product" value="premium" id="premium" />
            <i></i>Premium
        </label>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-4">
        <label className="radio">
            <input onChange={() => {serviceCalc()}} type="radio" name="radio-btn-product" value="excelium" id="excelium" />
            <i></i>Excelium
        </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to get the serviceCalc function to trigger the three other functions depending on which radio button is clicked like so:

```
const serviceCalc = () => {

    const standard1 = (document.getElementById("standard") as HTMLInputElement);
    const premium1 = (document.getElementById("premium") as HTMLInputElement);
    const excelium1 = (document.getElementById("excelium") as HTMLInputElement);

    if (standard1.checked){            
        standard();
    }
    else if (premium1.checked) {
        premium();
    }
    else if (excelium1.checked) {
        excelium();
    }
}
```

but when I select the standard option for example, this wont trigger:

```
    const standard = () => {

    console.log('stand_test')

}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The isssue is that your radio buttons are [*controlled*](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) (you have an `onChange` on them and you have `checked` on one of them), but you're only ever setting `checked` on standard. Since standard is always checked, clicking standard isn't changing anything, so the change event isn't raised.

Separately, `onChange={() => {serviceCalc()}}` should almost always be `onChange={serviceCalc}`.

Normally, when you're using controlled inputs, you store the state in the component state. Here's an example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [serviceLevel, setServiceLevel] = useState("standard");
    const serviceCalc = ({currentTarget: {value}}/*: {currentTarget: HTMLInputElement}*/) => {
        setServiceLevel(value);
        // If you need to run other functions here, you can do that
        // with an `if`/`else`/etc. on `value`, which is
        // `"standard"`, `"premium"`, or `"excelium"
    };
    
    // This is purely to show the new service level
    console.log(`service level is ${serviceLevel}`);

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <label className="radio">
                    <input onChange={serviceCalc} type="radio" name="radio-btn-product" value="standard" checked={serviceLevel === "standard"} />
                    <i></i>Standard
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <label className="radio">
                    <input onChange={serviceCalc} type="radio" name="radio-btn-product" value="premium" checked={serviceLevel === "premium"} />
                    <i></i>Premium
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <label className="radio">
                    <input onChange={serviceCalc} type="radio" name="radio-btn-product" value="excelium" checked={serviceLevel === "excelium"} />
                    <i></i>Excelium
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a parameter depending on which button was checked:

```
const serviceCalc = (service: "standard" | "premium" | "excelium") => {
    if (service === "standard") {
        return standard();
    }
    
    if (service === "premium") {
        return premium();
    }
    
    if (service === "excelium") {
        return excelium();
    }
}
```

And you would use it like so:

```
    <div className="col-md-4">
        <label className="radio">
            <input onChange={() => {serviceCalc("excelium")}} type="radio" name="radio-btn-product" value="excelium" id="excelium" />
            <i></i>Excelium
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Or just use `onChange={serviceCalc}` and let the event system do it. :-)